# My Print Vector Function doesn't seem to work. Can you help me find what's wrong?

Tags: c++, c++11

I've made this class and want to print it in a Vector. but it doesn't show the right output that I wanted. when I called it. But if I called the class alone, it worked. Where did I do wrong? It seems that my printVector() function isn't working. But I don't know why.
After I Ran it it shows this.

Input:

```
Name: Montag.  
Value: 1. 
Name: Montag    
Value: 1.  
Name: Montag.  
Value: 3.  
Name: q.  
Output.  
Name: Montag.  
Average: 1.66667.  
Name: Montag.  
Average: nan.  
Name: Dienstag.  
Average: nan.  
Name: Mittwoch.  
Average: nan.  
Name: Donnerstag.  
Average: nan.  
Name: Freitag.  
Average: nan.  
Name: Samstag.  
Average: nan.  
Name: Sontag.  
Average: nan.
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <exception>

using std::vector;
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::string;
using std::ostream;
using std::endl;

class Name_values{
public:
    Name_values();
    Name_values(const string& name, const vector<int>& values);
    Name_values(const string& name, const string& name2);
    void addValue(const int& value);
    void printAll();
    string getName()const{return name;}
    string getName2()const{return name2;}
    vector<int> getVector() const{return values;}
    
    
private:
    string name;
    string name2;
    vector<int> values;
};

Name_values::Name_values(){}
Name_values::Name_values(const string& name, const vector<int>& values): name(name), values(values){}
Name_values::Name_values(const string& name, const string& name2): name(name), name2(name2){}


void Name_values::addValue(const int& value){
    values.push_back(value);
}

void fill (vector<Name_values>& v, Name_values& o){
    v.push_back(o);
}

void Name_values::printAll(){
    double average = 0;
    double sum = 0;
   
    for(int i = 0; i< values.size(); ++i){
        sum += values.at(i);
    }
    if(values.size() == 0){
        average=0;
    }
    average = sum / values.size();
    
    cout<<"Name: "<< name <<endl<<"Average: "<< average <<endl;
}

void printVector(vector<Name_values>& v){
    for (Name_values& o : v){
        o.printAll();
    }
}

int main() {
    string name;
    int value{};
    vector<Name_values>week;
    Name_values mon("Montag", "Mo");
    Name_values die("Dienstag", "Di");
    Name_values mit("Mittwoch", "Mi");
    Name_values don("Donnerstag", "Don");
    Name_values fre("Freitag", "Fr");
    Name_values sam("Samstag", "Sa");
    Name_values son("Sontag", "So");
    fill(week,mon);
    fill(week,die);
    fill(week,mit);
    fill(week,don);
    fill(week,fre);
    fill(week,sam);
    fill(week,son);
    
    while(true){
        cout<<"Name: ";
        cin>>name;
        if(name == "q"){
            break;
        }
        cout<<"Value: ";
        cin>>value;
        
        if(name == mon.getName() || name == mon.getName2()){
            mon.addValue(value);
        }
        else if (name == die.getName() || name == die.getName2()){
            die.addValue(value);
        }
        else if (name == mit.getName() || name == mit.getName2()){
            mit.addValue(value);
        }
        else if (name == don.getName() || name == don.getName2()){
            don.addValue(value);
        }
        else if (name == fre.getName() || name == fre.getName2()){
            fre.addValue(value);
        }
        else if (name == sam.getName() || name == sam.getName2()){
            die.addValue(value);
        }
        else if (name == son.getName() || name == son.getName2()){
            die.addValue(value);
        }
        
    }
    mon.printAll();
    printVector(week);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `average = sum / values.size();` -- If `values` is empty, this line is executed, causing undefined behavior.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: I've put  if(values.size()==0){average =0}

Comment: @FrederickAnderson `I've put if(values.size()==0){average =0}` -- Read your code carefully.  Nothing prevents `average = sum/values.size()` from being executed.

Comment: What I don't understand is , when I call mon.printAll() it works, but when I used my function printVector(week) it doesn't

Comment: Offtopic: please provide contents of standard input separated from content of standard output. So your code could be run here: https://godbolt.org/z/h1sdbnEaE

Comment: the average problem is solved. u just added else.

Comment: What I don't understand is , when I call mon.printAll() it works, but when I used my function printVector(week) it doesn't  (still the problem)

Comment: The objects in `week` are copies of `mon`, `die`, `mit`, etc. Changing one of them will not change the other. Objects in vector are nover modified.

Comment: @FrederickAnderson *the average problem is solved. u just added else* -- And when you did that, did you see a difference in the output?  Instead of `nan`, maybe `0` is now outputted?  Given that, does that give you a hint on what the issue is?

Comment: yes it outputted 0

Comment: @FrederickAnderson -- Thus the reason for the output being is 0 is that the vector is empty.  Before posting the question, these are the minimal steps in debugging you should have done.  Then the question would be simply "why is my vector empty?" instead of "my program doesn't work".

Comment: I fixed the problem, I just change the location of the fills function to the bottom. Thanks guys

Comment: You didn't described desired output

Comment: Aside from the actual problem, you should really put your code on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). There is a lot that could be improved. Like, for instance, you should really learn how to use something like `std::map`.